# wordpress if statement if logged in then show different button

Tags: php, wordpress

i have homepage with 2 buttons that show up
How it works
Sign up

here is the php code i have and i beleive html code

```
<?php    
            $PricerrTheme_enable_how_it_works = get_option('PricerrTheme_enable_how_it_works');
            if($PricerrTheme_enable_how_it_works != "no"):

            $hthing = get_bloginfo('url'). '/wp-login.php?action=register';

            if(is_user_logged_in())
            $hthing = PricerrTheme_post_new_link();

            $Pricerr_main_how_it_works_link = get_option('Pricerr_main_how_it_works_link');
            if(!empty($Pricerr_main_how_it_works_link))
            {
                $hthing = $Pricerr_main_how_it_works_link;
            }   

        ?>
        <div class="main_graphic">
            <div class="main_graphic_inner">

                 <div class="test_line_1"><?php echo stripslashes(get_option('Pricerr_main_how_it_works_line1')) ?></div>
                 <div class="test_line_2"><?php echo stripslashes(get_option('Pricerr_main_how_it_works_line2')) ?></div>
                 <div class="test_line_3">

                 <ul class="duo_buttons">
                   <li class="lft"><a href="<?php echo get_option('PricerrTheme_button_1_link') ?>"><?php echo get_option('PricerrTheme_button_1_caption') ?></a></li>
                   <li class="rght"><a href="<?php echo get_option('PricerrTheme_button_2_link') ?>"><?php echo get_option('PricerrTheme_button_2_caption') ?></a></li>
                 </ul> 

                 </div>   
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; endif; ?>
```

were the code shows

```
 <ul class="duo_buttons">
                   <li class="lft"><a href="<?php echo get_option('PricerrTheme_button_1_link') ?>"><?php echo get_option('PricerrTheme_button_1_caption') ?></a></li>
                   <li class="rght"><a href="<?php echo get_option('PricerrTheme_button_2_link') ?>"><?php echo get_option('PricerrTheme_button_2_caption') ?></a></li>
                 </ul>
```

am trying to use if statement like this but it dont work it shows my if statement on page instead.

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
} else {
<ul class="duo_buttons">
                   <li class="lft"><a href="<?php echo get_option('PricerrTheme_button_1_link') ?>"><?php echo get_option('PricerrTheme_button_1_caption') ?></a></li>
                   <li class="rght"><a href="<?php echo get_option('PricerrTheme_button_2_link') ?>"><?php echo get_option('PricerrTheme_button_2_caption') ?></a></li>
                 </ul>
}
```

and here is the full code edited

```
<?php

            $PricerrTheme_enable_how_it_works = get_option('PricerrTheme_enable_how_it_works');
            if($PricerrTheme_enable_how_it_works != "no"):

            $hthing = get_bloginfo('url'). '/wp-login.php?action=register';

            if(is_user_logged_in())
            $hthing = PricerrTheme_post_new_link();

            $Pricerr_main_how_it_works_link = get_option('Pricerr_main_how_it_works_link');
            if(!empty($Pricerr_main_how_it_works_link))
            {
                $hthing = $Pricerr_main_how_it_works_link;
            }        
        ?>
        <div class="main_graphic">
            <div class="main_graphic_inner">

                 <div class="test_line_1"><?php echo stripslashes(get_option('Pricerr_main_how_it_works_line1')) ?></div>
                 <div class="test_line_2"><?php echo stripslashes(get_option('Pricerr_main_how_it_works_line2')) ?></div>
                 <div class="test_line_3">
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
} else {
                 <ul class="duo_buttons">
                   <li class="lft"><a href="<?php echo get_option('PricerrTheme_button_1_link') ?>"><?php echo get_option('PricerrTheme_button_1_caption') ?></a></li>
                   <li class="rght"><a href="<?php echo get_option('PricerrTheme_button_2_link') ?>"><?php echo get_option('PricerrTheme_button_2_caption') ?></a></li>
                 </ul>   
                 </div>    
            </div>
}
        </div>
```

and once i get this if statement to work i will just add button codes on true and false area.

so if logged in then show different buttons
if not logged in which is else then shwo sign up

Answer (score 1):

You missed PHP tags in your code...

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>


<?php } else { ?>
                 <ul class="duo_buttons">
                   <li class="lft"><a href="<?php echo get_option('PricerrTheme_button_1_link') ?>"><?php echo get_option('PricerrTheme_button_1_caption') ?></a></li>
                   <li class="rght"><a href="<?php echo get_option('PricerrTheme_button_2_link') ?>"><?php echo get_option('PricerrTheme_button_2_caption') ?></a></li>
                 </ul>

<?php } ?>
```